# Cucumber tags as TestNG group in QAF and Spring boot environment

Tags: testng, spring-test, cucumber-java, qaf, testng-annotation-test

I have 4 tests in a feature file with 2 different tags @first and @then.
I would like @first tests to run first with parallelism and @then tests to run after all @first tests finished, with parallelism too.

The project is here :
https://github.com/marcesso/qafTesting

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.qmetry.qaf.automation.cucumber.QAFCucumberPlugin", "pretty", "html:target"},
        /*tags = {"@Ignore"},*/
        features = {"src/test/resources/my/custom/packagename/testing"})
public class RunnerTest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    @Test(description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios", groups = {"first"})
    public void runScenarioFirst(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) throws Throwable {
        super.runScenario(pickleWrapper,featureWrapper);

    }
    @Test(description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios", groups = {"then"}, dependsOnMethods =
            "runScenarioFirst")
    public void runScenarioThen(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper) throws Throwable {
        super.runScenario(pickleWrapper,featureWrapper);
    }

    @Override
    @DataProvider(name = "scenarios", parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    }

}
```

The issue is that all tests run twice (once per test method) and the "groups" attribute of @Test annotation does not filter tests as I expected (very bottom at https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html)

There is no parallelism at all too.

I tried to filter pickles in tests methods but tests that did not match the condition were displayed as passed even if not run

```
if(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getTags().contains("@first")) {
            super.runScenario(pickleWrapper,featureWrapper);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In above example of `RunnerTest`, GherkinClient from qaf doesn't come in to picture because you are using cucumber runner. `GherkinScenarioFactory` and `BDDTestFactory2`(with qaf 2.1.15+) are GherkinClient implementation of QAF. When you are using any of them, you don't need above `RunnerTest` class. `BDDTestFactory2` is preferred over `GherkinScenarioFactory` and it supports additional syntax features on top of standard gherkin syntax.

When you are using cucumber runner (`RunnerTest` class in your case), tags are not considered as TestNG groups. If you want to use cucumber runner to run feature file you need to handle it using **cucumber options**. AFAIK, What you are looking for can't be achieved with single class when using cucumber runner.

When you are using qaf you can use [BDD2Factory](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#running-tests-with-specific-groups) instead of cucumber test class. You can provide xml configuration considering scenario as TestNG test case. You can mix and match different configuration options supported by TestNG same as executing Test written in java. In your case it may look like below:

```
<suite name="QAF Demo" verbose="0" parallel="false" data-provider-thread-count="10">

<test name="First"  parallel="methods"  thread-count="5">
   <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="first" />
      </run>
   </groups>
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2" />
   </classes>
</test>

<test name="second"  parallel="methods"  thread-count="5">
   <groups>
      <run>
        <include name="then" />
      </run>
   </groups>
   <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.text.BDDTestFactory2" />
   </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

You also can utilize [metadata filter](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#running-tests-with-specific-meta-data). Groups/Tags are also considered as [meta data](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario-meta-data.html) of testcase by qaf.
So instead of :

```
<groups>
  <run>
    <include name="first" />
  </run>
</groups>
```

you can simply provide `include` parameter as below:

```
   <parameter name="include" value="{'groups': ['first']}" />
```

I want to reiterate here that above features only available when you are running using  `BDDTestFactory2` but not available when using cucumber runner. Refer [using qaf-bdd-runner](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#using-qaf-cucumber-with-qaf-bdd-runner)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately, I'm afraid I cannot use pure TestNG as I need some SpringBoot features in the rest of my testing project.
I tried to extend some of cucumber classes to add the tag filter during the Object[][] building but all classes I tried to extend are final and fields are often non public. Even with reflection, the complexity is too high, too many code should be re written to have something easy to maintain
I'm a bit disappointed not to be able to extend classes as I think it shouldn't be very difficult nor dangerous

Comment: Don't worry, springboot feature should work as is as working with cucumber runner. Give it try. You can keep continue using cucumber step.

Comment: I gave a try yes, but I cannot have parallelism in the github project and when I reported on the real project I had errors

Comment: springboot feature should work as is in pure TestNG. Regarding parallelism, you need to set thread count and  parallel mode in testng config file. also set `global.datadriven.parallel=true` refer https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html

Comment: yes it works perfectly, the issue was a wrong version of testng in the pom of my real project. And I could fix parallelism thanks to your advises. Thanks a lot