# How to get cucumber steps with data provider and write json file?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

```
@Test(dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void runScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper, ITestContext iTestContext)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
        System.out.println(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getLine());
        String browser = iTestContext.getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browser");

        System.out.println("Running Test on Browser:" + browser + " Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (ExtentReportManager.getFeature(featureWrapper.toString()) == null) {
            ExtentReportManager.startFeature(featureWrapper.toString());
            ExtentReportManager.startScenario(featureWrapper.toString(), pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
            ExtentReportManager.getScenario().assignCategory(browser);

        } else {
            ExtentReportManager.startScenario(featureWrapper.toString(), pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
            ExtentReportManager.getScenario().assignCategory(browser);
        }
        DriverManager.setScenarioName(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
        DriverManager.setFeatureName(featureWrapper.toString());
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }
```

It's my runner class, and i want get my scenario steps and write them a json file and will add scenario results that json file after i will send that json to elasticsearch.
I have connection to elastic search and i send result after each scenario, but now i want send results after all of test scenarios after finish.

How to do that, can you help me?

Comment: so, the code is working, and you just need to know how to create the json?

Comment: Yes it's working but i can't get scenario steps in @test annotation method and created a json file. And i want add  steps to json file.

Comment: Maybe something from here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664422/in-cucumber-is-it-possible-to-programmatically-get-the-current-step-being-execu  If not.. you can pass the Json object where you want to add the steps, and inside each step from cucumber (Given/When etc) to add the name there

Comment: @Razvan Thank you, i'm not wrong they are have scenario variable on before method but i don't have i get scenario from data provider. Do you have any idea from data provider?

Comment: @Razvan I try that way but the line ` Field f = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");` it's give it to null do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [qaf-cucumeber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) which provides ready to use [elastic-search integration](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-elasticsearch). You can have [similar](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/elasticsearch/ElasticSearchIndexer.java) custom implementation as well. [TestCaseRunResult](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/qmetry/qaf/automation/integration/TestCaseRunResult.html) provides each step and checkpoint details. Moreover it also provides pure TestNG implementation for behavior driven testing to [utilize all TestNG features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228308/cucumber-tags-as-testng-group-in-qaf-and-spring-boot-environment/64232194#64232194).